# And condition on Join table on the same field multiple times in Sequelize NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I have one table called Users. One user can be present on multiple Email Group.

**User Table**
   id, name
   1, Sudhir Roy
   2, Rahul Singh

**Email Group Table**
   id, emailType, userID
   1, Promotional, 1
   2, Advertisement, 2
   3, Advertisement, 1

Need to get all users based on Email Type. (Email type is dynamic and send in array form like ["Promotional", "Advertisement"]

How can we find users based on the emailGroup.

- ["Advertisement"] return [1, 2] from user table
- ["Advertisement", "Promotional"] return [1] from user table.

I tried to use [Op.and] and [Op.in]. Both are not working.

Here is my sample code.

```
const user = User.findAll({
                where: {
                       "$emailGroup.emailType$": {
                               [Op.in]: emailGroup // Array from client
                       },
                },
                include: { 
                       model: EmailGroup
                }
             })
```

It works well when the email group array is single but not working when we try to find more than one email group.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add where clauses to the include object.

The resulting findAll would then become:

```
  const user = User.findAll({
    include: [
      {
        model: EmailGroup,
        where: {
          emailType$: {
            [Op.in]: emailGroup, // Array from client
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  });
```

As shown here in the docs: https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/querying.html#relations---associations

Comment: This will return if any element of array in In query matched with param. I want the result matched with parameters.